# memory swapping and cgroup

Tags: swap, virtual-memory, cgroups, memory-management

I wonder how is swapping mechanism implemented under the memory cgroup v1.

Most existing books (*understanding the linux kernel*, *professional linux kernel architecture*, *understanding the linux virtual memory manager)* don't mention cgroups at all, and still refer to the old data structures in 2.6.x kernel. I've also searched online but didn't find any detail about cgroup implementation.

Specifically, how does LRU work under the presence of memory cgroup? Is there a global LRU, i.e., global active/inactive lists? I doubt that's the case. Intuitively there should be a separate pair of in/active lists for each memory controller. But that's still unclear. For example, in the following case,

```
    [cgroup1]
      /   \
 [cgroup2] pid1
   /   \
 pid2 pid3
```

are there two pairs of active/inactive lists for cgroup1 and cgroup2, respectively? If that's the case, if cgroup1 is under memory pressure and needs to swap out some anonymous memory to the swap area, chances are cgroup1's kswapd will swap out some pages belonging to cgroup2. And thus cgroup2's active/inactive lists should also be modified reflecting page-outs.

Still, if the hierarchy goes deep, swapping at the top level would require modification at all children's lists. Wouldn't that cause some performance issue?